\hspace messes up overbrace
I would like to fix the incorrect overbrace and also place "ADD" over the array but without vertical divider, maybe having it a little bit over with a small line pointing the first element of the array. I'm sorry I'm a noob and I'm using latex for a university report for the first time. This is my code:
\setbox0=\hbox{$
    \arrayrulecolor{black} % Color for table borders
    \rowcolors{1}{white}{gray!30} % Alternate gray backgrounds in rows
    \hspace{-2em}\begin{array}{|c|*{27}{c|}}
    ADD   \\
    \hline
    \textbf{128} & \hphantom{0}0 &
    \textbf{64} & \hphantom{0}0 &
    \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{\hphantom{0}0}}  & \hphantom{0}0 &
    \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{\hphantom{0}0}}& \hphantom{0}0 &
    \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{\hphantom{0}0}} & \hphantom{0}0 &
    \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{\hphantom{0}0}} & \hphantom{0}0 &
    \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{\hphantom{0}0}} & \hphantom{0}0 &
    \textbf{100} & \hphantom{0}0 &
    \textbf{1} & \hphantom{0}0 &
    \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{0}} & \hphantom{0}0  &
    \textbf{5} &  \hphantom{0}0 \\
    \hline
    \end{array}
$}

% Underbrace without left bracket
\[
  \overbrace{\usebox0}^{K}
\]



\begin{center}
    % Draw a down-facing arrow from "ADD" to the first element
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    % Downward arrow pointing from "ADD" to the first element
    \draw[->, thick] (0, 1.5) -- (0, 0.5); % Draw the down arrow
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

    \vspace{-2.5em} % Negative space to bring elements closer
    
    \begin{center}
\[ 
    \arrayrulecolor{black} % Color for table borders
    \rowcolors{1}{gray!30}{gray!30} % Alternate gray backgrounds in rows
    \hspace{-2em}\begin{array}{|c|*{27}{c|}}
        \hline
    \hphantom{0}\textbf{128}\hphantom{0} & \textcolor{red}{31} &
    \textbf{64}& \textcolor{red}{31}&
    \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{64}}& \textcolor{red}{30}& 
    \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{64}}& \textcolor{red}{29}&
    \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{64}}& \textcolor{red}{28}& 
    \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{64}}& \textcolor{red}{27}& 
    \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{64}}& \textcolor{red}{26}& 
    \textbf{100}& \textcolor{red}{31}& 
    \textbf{1}& \textcolor{red}{31}& 
    \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{1}}& \textcolor{red}{30}& 
    \textbf{5}& \textcolor{red}{31} \\
    \hline
    
    \end{array} 
\]
\end{center}```


please always make an example a complete document that shows the problem, but never surround \[ with \begin{center} it does not center it, just adds spurious vertical space, so perhaps removing that would already fix your problem?

It's not really clear what you want, but it might be something like what follows.

Just one tabular environment
Columns have fixed width
The overbrace only extends over the columns after “ADD”; since the columns have fixed width, it's possible to know how long the overbrace should be.
I adjusted \tabcolsep so the table can be contained in the margins as set by geometry; depending on your setting you can play with that length.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newlength{\lenA}
\newlength{\lenB}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\small
\settowidth{\lenA}{ADD}
\settowidth{\lenB}{\textbf{00}}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3.7pt}

  \begin{tabular}{|w{c}{\lenA}|*{21}{w{c}{\lenB}|}}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textrm{ADD}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\makebox[0pt][l]{%
      $\overbrace{\hspace{\dimeval{21\lenB+40\tabcolsep+20\arrayrulewidth}}}^K$%
    }}
   \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{gray!30}% Alternate gray backgrounds in rows
    \textbf{128} & \hphantom{0}0 &
    \textbf{64} & \hphantom{0}0 &
    \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{\hphantom{0}0}} & \hphantom{0}0 &
    \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{\hphantom{0}0}} & \hphantom{0}0 &
    \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{\hphantom{0}0}} & \hphantom{0}0 &
    \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{\hphantom{0}0}} & \hphantom{0}0 &
    \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{\hphantom{0}0}} & \hphantom{0}0 &
    \textbf{100} & \hphantom{0}0 &
    \textbf{1} & \hphantom{0}0 &
    \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{0}} & \hphantom{0}0  &
    \textbf{5} &  \hphantom{0}0 \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\[-1.5ex]
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\left\downarrow\vbox to 15pt{}\right.$} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\[-1.5ex]
    \hline
    \rowcolor{gray!30} % Alternate gray backgrounds in rows
    \textbf{128} & \textcolor{red}{31} &
    \textbf{64}& \textcolor{red}{31}&
    \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{64}}& \textcolor{red}{30}& 
    \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{64}}& \textcolor{red}{29}&
    \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{64}}& \textcolor{red}{28}& 
    \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{64}}& \textcolor{red}{27}& 
    \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{64}}& \textcolor{red}{26}& 
    \textbf{100}& \textcolor{red}{31}& 
    \textbf{1}& \textcolor{red}{31}& 
    \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{1}}& \textcolor{red}{30}& 
    \textbf{5}& \textcolor{red}{31} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}



Thanks, this format is much better than the one i used! I didn't explain myself very well, but with small tweaks of your code I easily fixed the issue.
